# DOCKER_OPTS in Docker container 1.9.1-dind

Tags: docker, docker-compose

we want start a docker in a docker container with docker-compose.
For that we use this docker-compose.yml

```
some-docker:
  image: docker:1.9.1-dind
  privileged: true
  ports:
    - "2375:2375"
```

How can we commit the DOCKER_OPTS (--insecure-registry) to the container? Or it is possible to define some command-line args in the docker-compose file?
In the image docker:1.9.1-dind only two shell scripts to start the docker inside. The docker (in the container) don't use /etc/default/docker.

thx

Comment: Did you try to export the DOCKER_OPTS value (in the container shell session you are in, before running docker-compose)? See if the docker-compose up uses it in its session

Comment: With ´environment:
    DOCKER_OPTS: --insecure-registry=registry:5000´ (in docker-compose.yml) we get the DOCKER_OPTS in the container. So the problem is that the docker daemon don't use the OPTS.

Comment: What about setting it in the container shell session: `export  DOCKER_OPTS='...'`?

Answer (score 8):

`DOCKER_OPTS` is only used by certain Linux distributions in their `init` scripts to make it easy for the user to pass additional args, the Docker daemon itself only cares for arguments passed on start.

The image you are using is based on Alpine Linux with a [custom start script](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/7a61b09b70b0aba202019c6325821437981126f4/1.9/dind/dockerd-entrypoint.sh) as `entry point`. By the looks of it you just need pass any arguments to the daemon as docker `run command`. Try the following docker-compose.yml:

```
some-docker:
   image: docker:1.9.1-dind
   command: "--insecure-registry my.registry.com:5000"
   privileged: true
   ports:
     - "2375:2375"
```